# How to find the percolation path and highlight it?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, union

I use Quick Union algorithm to find if one of the first 5 sites are connected with one of the last 5 sites.

The first five sites have the same root, it's a penultimate array element. The last five sites have the same root as well. It's the last array element.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        this.union(i,this.array.length-2);
    }
    for (let j = this.array.length-this.number-2; j < this.array.length-2; j++) {
        this.union(j,this.array.length-1);
    }
```

I need to paint a path like this[image]

My code for highlighting the sites is:

```
let id =   this.array[this.array.length-2]
for (let i = 0; i < this.array.length-2; i++) {
    if(this.connected(i,id) && $("#result td").eq(i).hasClass('opened')){
        $("#result td").eq(i).css({'background':'blue'});
    }

}
```

It results:
[image]

But It's not right that 2 left sites are highlighted.
[image]
What Algorithm should i use to highlight only right path?

Connected method:

```
connected(p, q){
    return this.root(p) === this.root(q);
}
```

Root method

```
root(index){
    while(this.array[index] !== index) index = this.array[index];
    return index;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by right path, the path which is from start point to end point ?

Comment: Basically you don't want all the unblocked paths to get percolated right ?

Comment: a system percolates if we fill all open sites connected to the top row and that process fills some open site on the bottom row.

Comment: the open sites correspond to empty space through which water might flow, so that a system that percolates lets water fill open sites, flowing from top to bottom

Comment: If you just want to highlight the shortest path between the top and bottom rows, look up pathfinding algorithms, you just need to keep track of previous states (BFS will be sufficient). If you want to highlight the whole region that joins the top and bottom rows, use a flood-fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just want a basic Fill algorithm, but with 2 caveats. 1) You only want it to fill downwards as if water was flowing 2) you want the Fill() to be called on every empty space in the first (top) row, as if water was being poured accross the top.

```
var EMPTY = 0; // empty unfilled spot
var SOLID = 1; // solid spot
var FILLED = 2; // filled spot
var ROWS = 5; // # of rows of data indexed 0 to 4
var COLS = 5; // # of columns of data indexed 0 to 4
var data = [
    [1,0,0,1,1],
    [1,1,0,1,1],
    [0,1,0,0,1],
    [0,1,1,0,1],
    [0,1,1,0,1]
]; // data that matches the example

// check if a location is EMPTY
function isEmpty(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
    // valid row and col?
    if(rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex >= ROWS || colIndex < 0 || colIndex >= COLS) {
        return false;
    }
    // SOLID or FILLED already?
    if(grid[rowIndex][colIndex] !== EMPTY) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// replace EMPTY locations with FILLED locations
function fillDown(grid, startRow, startCol) {
    if(false === isEmpty(grid, startRow, startCol)) {
        return;
    }
    var nextLocation = [[startRow, startCol]]; // list of locations to process
    while(nextLocation.length > 0) { // loop
        var loc = nextLocation.pop();
        var r = loc[0]; // row index
        var c = loc[1]; // column index
        // fill the empty location
        grid[r][c] = FILLED;
        // try to fill the locations to the LEFT, RIGHT and DOWN from the current location
        if(isEmpty(grid, r, c - 1)) { // left
            nextLocation.push([r, c - 1]);
        }
        if(isEmpty(grid, r, c + 1)) { // right
            nextLocation.push([r, c + 1]);
        }
        if(isEmpty(grid, r + 1, c)) { // down
            nextLocation.push([r + 1, c]);
        }
    }
}

// call fillDown() for the first row of the data (water pouring accross the top)
for(var c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
    fillDown(data, 0, c);
}

// show the result
alert(data.join('\n'));
```

Extra note, row and column indexes for a 2d array can be converted to a 1d array index by the formula: index = (r * COLS) + c, so the last location in the data row = 4, col = 4 would be 4 * 5 + 4 == 24, the index for the last location in a 1d array.